# no attribute '_meta' error when trying to run method to delete a row from a URL called by .get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatable

It's a part of project in django framework.
In a javascript file I'm writing a code segment to .get() a URL

```
e.g. /delete/student/<id_of_student> .
.
.
$.get($(this).attr('href'), location.reload(true), function(data){ alert("Put in bin !!"); });
.
.
```

When it will be called , from urls.py it will be mapped to a function which will put the row in trash_bin and from page the row will be deleted after reload.

But in runserver console it's throwing error like:

```
concrete_model = model._meta.concrete_model

AttributeError: type object 'builtin_function_or_method' has no attribute '_meta'
```

But in console.log showing correct url, say /delete/student/123.

Here's the trash part from models.py :

> class TrashAction(models.Model):
>       user        = models.ForeignKey(User)
>       timestamp   = models.DateTimeField()
>
> ```
> def __unicode__(self):
>     return "%d items by %s on %s" % (self.trashitem_set.count(), self.user, self.timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
> ```
>
> class TrashItem(models.Model):
>       json_data   = models.TextField()
>       contenttype = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
>       action      = models.ForeignKey(TrashAction)
>
> ```
> def __unicode__(self):
>     data = json.loads(self.json_data)[0]
>     return "%s[%d]" % (data['model'], data['pk'])
> ```

---

Here's view of trash.py :

> def move_to_trash(request, obj):
>       """
>       Moves an object to the trash bin.
>       """
>
> ```
> c = Collector(using='default')
> c.collect([obj])
>
> action = None
>
> with transaction.atomic():
>     action = TrashAction()
>     action.user = request.user
>     action.timestamp = datetime.now()
>     action.save()
>
>     for i in c.instances_with_model():
>         item = TrashItem()
>         item.action = action
>         item.contenttype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(i[1])
>         item.json_data = serializers.serialize('json', [ i[1] ])
>         item.save()
>
> obj.delete()
> ```
>
> def delete_product(request, student_id):
>       move_to_trash(request, id)

Could anybody please help me to understand why this error is coming?

Comment: What is `model`? it appears to be a method.

Comment: Can you share `models.py` and `views.py`?

Comment: ('^delete/student/(?P<student_id>d+)$',trash_student),

Comment: model.py can't share . but In related places it's models.Model only

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11042831) button to update your question with new information, although without an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your question isn't answerable.

Comment: I hvae given the available data. Please let me know, where is the mistake?